# Detect bad frames in OpenCV 2.4.9

Tags: c++, opencv, ffmpeg, motion

I know the title is a bit vague but I'm not sure how else to describe it.

CentOS with ffmpeg + OpenCV 2.4.9. I'm working on a simple motion detection system which uses a stream from an IP camera (h264).

Once in a while the stream hiccups and throws in a "bad frame" (see pic-bad.png link below). The problem is, these frames vary largely from the previous frames and causes a "motion" event to get triggered even though no actual motion occured.

The pictures below will explain the problem.

Good frame (motion captured):

[image: Good Frame]

Bad frame (no motion, just a broken frame):

[image: Bad Frame]

The bad frame gets caught randomly. I guess I can make a bad frame detector by analyzing (looping) through the pixels going down from a certain position to see if they are all the same, but I'm wondering if there is any other, more efficient, "by the book" approach to detecting these types of bad frames and just skipping over them.

Thank You!

EDIT UPDATE:

The frame is grabbed using a C++ motion detection program via `cvQueryFrame(camera);` so I do not directly interface with ffmpeg, OpenCV does it on the backend. I'm using the latest version of ffmpeg compiled from git source. All of the libraries are also up to date (h264, etc, all downloaded and compiled yesterday). The data is coming from an RTSP stream (ffserver). I've tested over multiple cameras (dahua 1 - 3 MP models) and the frame glitch is pretty persistent across all of them, although it doesn't happen continuously, just once on a while (ex: once every 10 minutes).

Comment: How do you grab the frame?

Comment: It is possibly the ffmpeg codec. But you can test it on a recorded video. [See this](https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2011-June/000297.html)

Comment: The frame is grabbed using the C++ motion detection program via `cvQueryFrame(camera);` so I do not directly interface with ffmpeg, OpenCV does it on the backend. I'm using the latest version of ffmpeg compiled from git source. All of the libraries are also up to date. The data is coming from an RTSP stream. I've tested over multiple cameras (dahuas) and the frame glitch is pretty persistent, although it doesn't happen continuously, just once on a while (ex: once every 10 minutes).

Comment: `cvQueryFrame(camera);` I think is C version, but can you post some code? Mabe you should put a `cv::waitKey(10);` at the end of the for loop, it could be too fast (maybe...)

Comment: I do have have wait code in there, `waitKey(50)`. I've seen this before quite a lot, but when watching a video @ ~30fps, a single frame like that out of 30 seen every second is not a big deal, however, when doing frame analysis it is. I'm a bit surprised no one has seen behavior like this with ffmpeg. I'm 99% sure it's caused by some decoding issue on the ffmpeg side, I'm just curious if there is any way to prevent it or auto-detect and drop.

Comment: I have seen this kind of stuff when I was trying to save images and I was force-stopping the application. Then I was getting an incomplete image. Try to update ffmpeg, if not done yet

Comment: Suggestion reduces the camera FPS to avoid this kind of corrupted frames

Answer (score 4):

What comes to my mind in first approach is to check dissimilarity between example of valid frame and the one we are checking by counting the pixels that are not the same. Dividing this number by the area we get percentage which measures dissimilarity. I would guess above 0.5 we can say that tested frame is invalid because it differs too much from the example of valid one.

This assumption is only appropriate if you have a static camera (it does not move) and the objects which can move in front of it are not in the shortest distance (depends from focal length, but if you have e.g. wide lenses so objects should not appear less than 30 cm in front of camera to prevent situation that objects "jumps" into a frame from nowhere and has it size bigger that 50% of frame area).

Here you have opencv function which does what I said. In fact you can adjust dissimilarity coefficient more large if you think motion changes will be more rapid. Please notice that first parameter should be an example of valid frame.

```
bool IsBadFrame(const cv::Mat &goodFrame, const cv::Mat &nextFrame) {
    // assert(goodFrame.size() == nextFrame.size())

    cv::Mat g, g2;
    cv::cvtColor(goodFrame, g, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cv::cvtColor(nextFrame, g2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::Mat diff = g2 != g;

    float similarity = (float)cv::countNonZero(diff) / (goodFrame.size().height * goodFrame.size().width);

    return similarity > 0.5f;
}
```

Comment: This approach might work, I haven't tested it yet (I'm not in front of the machine with the code) but here is an issue... The purpose of the C++ app + OpenCV in this case is to detect motion. Motion is detected by comparing the current frame to the previous frame for changes (already), this is why we're seeing "motion" when there currently isn't any... Now, if a car pulls in front of the camera, it will result in a huge change of pixels/colors/etc, but I think that it would also trigger the "IsBadFrame" function above.

Answer (score 1):

You do not mention if you use ffmpeg command line or libraries, but in the latter case you can check the bad frame flag (I forgot its exact description) and simply ignore those frames.

Comment: Added in post edit. It's via C++ and OpenCV, not through ffmpeg directly.

Answer (score 0):

remove `waitKey(50)` or change it to `waitKey(1)`. I think opencv does not spawn a new thread to perform capture. so when there is a pause, it confuses the buffer management routines, causing bad frames..maybe?

I have dahua cameras and observed that with higher delay, bad frames are observed. And they go away completely with `waitKey(1)`. The pause does not necessarily need to come from `waitKey`. Calling routines also cause such pauses and result in bad frames if they are taking long enough.

This means that there should be minimum pause between consecutive frame grabs.the solution would be to use two threads to perform capture and processing separately.

Comment: Ahh, very interesting. I'm going to try this tomorrow. Thanks for sharing! Will update the thread with result.

Comment: @user3630380: Did reducing wait work? Also what solution did you arrive at? Thank you.