# How to detect Bad frames and ignore them while capturing with opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, opencv3.0, flicker

I am trying to capture images with opencv's `VideoCapture()` with `python`.
But I am getting a lot a bad frames:

i.e., flickered images.
Can anyone help with the solution to detect this bad frame and ignore it and only capture if the image is good.

Comment: my preferred solutions would be to get a new camera or fix whatever is wrong with it. if you can't help it you have to define what makes a good or bad image. check each image for those features and decide wether too keep or discard the frame. depending on the frame rate you might have to do this asynchronously. maybe you can do something by comparing subsequent frames. all in all your post is too broad and cannot be answered properly

Comment: Thanks for the response. the last resort is to change the camera. I would like to try to find a way to remove the flickered images thru processing the current frame and the previous frame. would this be a good idea, as suggested in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23620388/detect-bad-frames-in-opencv-2-4-9)

Comment: if subsequent frames are very similar than this is a viable way. but as I said, it is unnecessary processing. which in most cases cannot be done without losing framerate or doing it asynchronously